# How would I Multi-Thread This Python Program?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a Python Script that tries to guess a phrase based on dumping out random digits until the right ones are put together. Obviously this is very slow, because no digits are kept when they are guessed correct, each phrase is randomly guessed and the chances of it getting it correct are very slim.

The program works, I have got it to successfully guess a two digit phrase in about 10 seconds, and a 3 digit in 30. Anything above takes forever. I was wondering If Multi threading would help here. If so, How I would Multi thread this program?

I have had no prior experience with threading in Python, and it seems a bit confusing.

Any Ideas On How I Would Do This?

Code:

```
import string
import random
import time



possibleCharacters = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase + """ '".,!?;:/\?<>-_=+"""

target = "guessme"
print("Phrase is 'guessme', so just enter 7 below.")
digits = int(input("How many digits in the phrase? \n] "))


attemptThis = ''.join(random.choice(possibleCharacters) for i in range(digits))
attemptNext = ''

completed = False
generation = 0
generationdisplay = 0



while completed == False:


    generationdisplay += 1

    print(attemptThis + " - " + str(generationdisplay))

    attemptNext = ''
    completed = True
    for i in range(digits):
        if attemptThis[i] != target[i]:
            completed = False
            attemptNext += random.choice(possibleCharacters)
        else:
            attemptNext += str(digits)
    generation += 1
    attemptThis = attemptNext


print("Phrase Cracked! That took " + str(generation) + " generation(s)." + "Phrase was: " + target)
```

If you need any extra info, I am happy to provide it.

_MouseBatteries

Comment: *Technically* multithreading will help... but it will give you a speedup at best *linear* in the number of additional threads. (E.g., you throw 100 CPU cores at it, you get a 100x speedup.) The problem you're going to run into is that the number of combinations to try increases *exponentially* as you make the string longer. For a 2-character string, you have something like (26*2+10+20)^2 possibilities... at 7, that exponent of course goes up to 7. No amount of threads will make that run quickly! (Especially in Python...)

Comment: Okay. Thanks @s3cur3. Maybe I will try to implement guessing popular vowels, and such first. And maybe a system for every character that it gets correct, gets saved.

Comment: Sure. You might also look into starting with [a dictionary "attack"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack) and only falling back to brute force random guessing after that. (And FWIW, I didn't downvote you—this is a well-formed question, with a good code sample! :) )